# $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) \cdot f(−x)\leq 0$ for all $x$. Is $f$ a onto function and does $f$ have a zero?

Tags: functions, derivatives

**Question is:**
Given that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) \cdot f(−x)\leq 0$ for all $x$.

- Is $f$ always an onto function ?
- Does $f$ has zero in all examples?

**My thoughts:**

*Firstly I think $f$ is an odd function so its onto. Can you give an anti example for this? I couldn't find.*

*Frankly, I don't fully understand this part. What is mean that $f$ has zero? Could you explain?*

Comment: You cannot conclude that $f$ is odd (though odd functions will have the desired property). All you know is that $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ cannot both be positive or both be negative; you do not know that $f(x)=-f(-x)$.

Comment: Do you really think that every odd function is onto? Draw some pictures, and think about well-known functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler, $f(x) = 0$ satisfies $f(x) \cdot f(-x) \leq 0$ for all $x$, but is not onto.

By the hypothesis we must have $0 \leq f(0)^{2} \leq 0 \implies f(0) = 0$ and $f$ has a zero.

The following is a longer argument based on the intermediate value theorem:

If $f(x) < 0$ for all $x$, then $f(x) \cdot f(-x) > 0$ and similarly for the case where $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$. This means the codomain must contain at least one nonnegative number and at least one nonpositive number.

Hence there must be points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, such that $f(x_{1}) \leq 0$ and $f(x_{2}) \geq 0$ with $x_{1} \leq x_{2}$. If either of the points are zeroes, we are done. Otherwise, $f(x_{1}) < 0$ and $f(x_{2}) > 0$, and  $x_{1} < x_{2}$ since $f$ is a function.

Since $f$ is continuous by the hypothesis, one may use the intermediate value theorem to see that there exists a $c \in (x_{1},x_{2})$ such that $f(c) = 0$, which means $f$ has a zero.

Comment: One can simplify this a bit - we don't need to manipulate any statements like "for all $x$" - more to the point, your argument shows if $f(x)<0$ then $f(-x)\geq 0$ and vice versa - so you can choose your $x_1$ and $x_2$ just by choosing whatever $c$ you like and saying $x_1=c$ and $x_2=-c$. (...and I might propose that $c=0$ is a particular compelling choice)

Comment: I guess from your observation and the hypothesis directly, if $f(0) \leq 0$, then $f(0) \geq 0 \implies f(0) = 0$, and similarly for the case $f(0) \geq 0$. That is much simpler, oops.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\sin x$ satisfies the hypothesis, but it is not onto.

Putting $x =0$ we get $0 \leq f(0)^{2} \leq 0$ so $f(0)$ must be $0$.

Comment: Why are you taking limits? You don’t need to let $x$ “go to” $0$; you can just let $x$ **be** equal to $0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are right. Continuity is not even needed.

Answer (score 1):

f(x) = arctan(x) disproves part 1 since it satisfies the hypothesis but fails to be onto.

The IVT guarantees there is a 0 in all examples.